# NavigationUI with actionbar icon clicks result in fragments fading in and out

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-animation, android-navigation-editor

I have an actionbar with icons that, when clicked, shows cooresponding fragments on the screen. This is independent of the navigation graph. I'm using the `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected` method to navigate to respective fragments when the cooresponding icons are clicked in the actionbar. When I use the navigation graph to navigate between fragments through button click actions etc within fragments, there is no animation, but when I click on the actionbar icons, it causes the cooresponding fragments to slowly fade in and out. What do I have to do to disable this?

**Main activity containing the NavHostFragment:**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment)

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

        //supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {

        onBackPressed()
        return true

    }

    //TODO: add options in overflow menu to add new category and a new task
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId)
        {
            R.id.app_settings -> {

                //just to test it out
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_activity_container), "app settings option clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                true}

            R.id.main_pomo_settings -> {

                //just to test it out
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_activity_container), "pomo settings option clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                true}
        }

        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item!!, navController)  || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question. You have to disable the animations by creating the following empty animation files in the anim folder:

res/anim/nav_default_enter_anim.xml

res/anim/nav_default_exit_anim.xml

res/anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim.xml

res/anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim.xml

1. Right click the res folder (if no anim folder exists) and select `New -> Android Resource File`
2. Select animation for the resource type
3. Type `nav_default_enter_anim` for the file name and click OK.
4. Repeat for the other files but this time right clicking on the anim folder.

Put the following in each file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Empty to disable animation-->
</set>
```

Comment: Why isn't this in the official documentation to begin with?